# So i am solving a Fractional knapsack but there is error sort operation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

```
#include<iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class knapsack
{
public:
    int profit[4]={280,100,120,120};
    int weight[4]={40,10,20,24};
    int total=60;
    float fraction[];
    int fractotal=0;
    int profittotal=0;
    int getprofit=0;
    float temp[4]={0,0,0,0};
    float temp1=0;
    float temp2=0;
    float temp3=0;
    float temp4=0;
void displayvalues()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"The profit and weight of the item"<<"\n";
    cout<<"The Profit"<<"  ";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<profit[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<"The weights"<<"  ";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<weight[i]<<" ";
    }
}
float fractionalknapsack()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        fraction[i]=profit[i]/weight[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<"The values are"<<"\n";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        profittotal=profittotal+profit[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<fraction[i]<<"\n";
        fractotal= fractotal+fraction[i];
    }
    if(fractotal<=total)
    {
        cout<<"The maximum possible value is"<<profittotal;
    }
    else if(fractotal>=total)
    {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(fraction[i]<fraction[j])
                {
                    temp2=fraction[i];
                    fraction[i]=fraction[j];
                    fraction[j]=temp2;
                    temp3=profit[i];
                    profit[i]=profit[j];
                    profit[j]=temp2;
                    temp4=weight[i];
                    weight[i]=weight[j];
                    weight[j]=temp4;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

    while(getprofit<total)
    {
        if(getprofit+weight[i]<=total)
        {
            temp[i]=1;
            getprofit+=weight[i];
        }
        else
        {
            temp[i]=(total-getprofit)/weight[i];
            getprofit=total;
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    cout<<temp;

        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        temp1+=profit[i]*temp[i];
    }
    cout<<temp1;
}
};
int main()
{
    knapsack k;
    k.displayvalues();
    k.fractionalknapsack();
}
```

So here if you see i have am solving fractional knapsack question with my approach but there is a error in sort operation so can someone give me the solution for this. It would really helpfull. So in the function of fractional knapsack you will se a else if where I have to do sort if the next value to the previous value is greater i used sort operation but is not working. So someone can help me with this.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working".

Comment: being specific that my sort operation is not working if thats not gonna then i can't assign value for fractioning so how would i do sorting

Comment: There are countless ways in which something can "not work". Does it produce the wrong values (which ones?), crash (how?), not compile (what are the exact errors?), something else?

Comment: its show garbage values at the output

Comment: it doesnt shows any error

Comment: I can't find a single compiler willing to accept that code, due to the (non-standard and invalid) flexible array member `fraction`.

Comment: then what I have to do what changes should i make

Comment: A good first step would be to not try to use flexible array members. If it's of a fixed size, use that size; if it's of varying size, use `std::vector`.